# Is it possible to query a mongoose model using a text field in an associated model?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two mongoose models with a relationship like this:

```
const ProductSchema: Schema = new Schema(
{
    name: String,
    category: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category'
    },
    description: String
}
```

with a text index on `name` and `description` fields.

The category schema looks like this

```
const CategorySchema: Schema = new Schema(
{
    title: String
}
```

with text index on `title` field.

Is it possible to have a fulltext search for products such that the keywords can include the category title or even just a text search with the category title alone?

Answer (score 1):

You could find all Products, **populate** them, and then filter using `.filter()`.

The code would look like this (I guess you know how to gather user input, so I skipped that part):

```
// If you have saved the user input in a variable
const searchFieldInput = "foo";

const products = await Product
  .find({}) // Finds all Products in the DB
  .populate("category"); // Populates the Category field

// Filter the products array based on the user input
const filteredProducts = products.filter((product) =>
  product.category.includes(searchFieldInput)
)
```